# Can you bypass the iPhone's power or volume buttons

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Is it possible to 'hack' or develop an app that lets you launch an app by pressing an iPhones power button or volume buttons or possibly from the passcode screen?

As an example: pressing the power button 5 times launches the app or sends an emergency SMS. Or entering a certain code into the passcode / lock screen sends an SMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. All these features are managed by a different process than your application, and you cannot directly influence that process. You can develop a JailBreak tweak that will allow you to do so, but obviously this is not for Apple AppStore.

Comment: Thanks Leo. I'm looking for the quickest way to send a panic sms. Any recommendations or ideas?

Comment: Best I can think of as if iOS8 is to have a Notification Center widget.

Comment: You could also ask siri to launch it for you, perhaps application: openURL:  in your app delegate, there may be a custom verbal message from siri that could be pushed across ?

Comment: There is not API that can influence Siri beyond "open <appname>" to open your app.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking about is against the Apple Developer TOS. If you do it, you will not pass the App Store Review process and hence will not be able to distribute vie the iTunes App Store. If you don't care about that, then there may be jail break hacks that can help you with that.

Comment: Thanks Cliff. I'm looking for the quickest way to send a panic sms. Any recommendations or ideas?